# Google map with Php to Js variable

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

i've been trying to power a google map by using a certain variable of a wordpress post, the idea is to take the data from the variable, change it to js and then insert it in the map code, this how i'm doing it

```
if( isset($post->ID) ){
    $gmap_lat           =   esc_html( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_latitude', true));
    $gmap_long          =   esc_html( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_longitude', true));
    $property_add_on    =   ' data-post_id="'.$post->ID.'" data-cur_lat="'.$gmap_lat.'" data-cur_long="'.$gmap_long.'" ';
    $closed_height      =   get_current_map_height($post->ID);
    $open_height        =   get_map_open_height($post->ID);
    $open_close_status  =   get_map_open_close_status($post->ID);
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    var name= "<?php echo $gmap_lat; ?>";
    var name2= "<?php echo $gmap_long; ?>";
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(name ,name2 );
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}
</script>'; 
}
```

And then the map shows up in the map_canvas div. The problem i'm having is that the map loads the controls and frame but does not show any map inside, i was thinking i'm probably using the variables wrong, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var name= "' . $gmap_lat . '";
var name2= "' . $gmap_long . '";
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(name ,name2 );
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }
</script>';
```

and if `$gmap_lat` and `$gmap_long` are numbers then don't use quotes.

Comment: Thanks man, yeah its numbers, but still only work with the quotes.